# How to query MongoDB in a Diacritic Insensitive way using LINQ and TextSearchOptions

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I would like to query mongo using a Diacritic Insensitive way, as described in this doc:

> http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/2.2/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_TextSearchOptions_DiacriticSensitive.htm

How can I use this on LINQ?

for example, now I have a query like this, using C# and LINQ:

```
DB.collection.Find(d => d.Name.ToLower().Contains("paroquia"))
```

I have some documents that contains diacritics and they are not being returned, for example, documents with Name **Paróquia**, should be found when user search for **paroquia**, or a partial (contains), **paro**

I also tried this:

```
await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<MyDoc>.IndexKeys.Text(_ => _.Name));
```

But still not able to search in Diacritic Insensitive way.

What code can I add to make this query Diacritic Insensitive?

Comment: Use `DB.collection.Find(Builders<MyDoc>.Filter.Text("paroquia"))` to use text search after you have created text index on name field.